# Making a form by having a view

Tags: views, forms

I am trying to convert a view to a form as follows:

*I need to have a table of articles (which can be produces easily by views) and inserting a checkbox next to each row (article), and a button next to this table as Submit button.
The created form out of the articles` view should be able to initialize the value of the checkboxes before showing them (which can be done somehow by form_alter).*

So, the problem is that I really don't know how to create this form.

I used VBO, but VBO does the operation for the selected rows! I need a method which can help me to set the values of checkboxes by code, before views render, and when the submit button is clicked, whole rows should be checked!

can you please suggest a tested & working solution?

thanks

Comment: Please explain your requirement a little more

Comment: ok , I revise the text

Comment: I think this link may help you https://isovera.com/blog/programmatically-creating-forms-views-drupal-7

Comment: Thank you! I have already implemented this solution, and the views_form_submit and '#element_validate' sections are not working at all. That's why I mentioned to receive a tested & working solution. Again, thank you

Comment: Moreover, the author of that website is not responding the comments and questions about his solution.

Comment: Ok, also form can be included using header and footer section of views and and a custom field to add checkbox against each field.  It would be simple php form not drupal form

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17150/discussion-between-raj10-and-ehsan).

Answer (score 0):

`view_form_submit` is not working in D7, you have to use the `hook_form_alter` and then you have to change the `#submit`:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'custom_form_submit';
```